# How can I make the value of a variable equal the content of a text field in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to happen is for a user to be able to type a number into a text field,and by clicking a button transfer the value of the text field to the variable. And I want to do this without refreshing the page, so using input type="submit" is not what I've done, I've used input type="button".
And I'd prefer to accomplish my goal using jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var textAlteredStyle;
function setTL() {
textAlteredStyle = document.getElementById('alterTL').value;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
document.getElementById('alter').onclick = setTL;
$('#theModified').replace('<input type="text" id="theModified" style="width: 153px; border-top-left-radius: '+textAlteredStyle+'px;">');
});
});
</script>




</head>

<body>



<input type="text" id="theModified" style="width: 153px;">

<br><br>


<input type="text" id="alterTL">pixels

<br>

<input type="button" value="Alter" id="alter">
```

Comment: This should be rather trivial if you add some code and tell us what you've tried.

Comment: You should start with [an introductory tutorial to JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills).

Comment: @adeneo I'm trying to see if I can alter the border radius of an element by typing the desired radius into a box and submitting. I'm not sure if it is possible or what I'm doing wrong, but I've posted the code above.

Comment: @user2255654 - of course you can. Like [***THIS FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/ykRnp/) !!!

Answer (score 1):

you can initialize variable with element value:

jQuery:

```
var myVariable= $('#elementId').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <input type="text" id="txtInput"></input>
    <input type="button" id="btnInput"></input>

    var test = '';
    $('#btnInput').click(function()
    {
        test = $('#txtInput').val();
        return false;
    });
```

Try This:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#alter').click(function()
        {
            $('#theModified').val($('#alterTL').val());
            return false;
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code,

```
var myvar;
function setTextFieldValue(){
    myvar = document.getElementById('textFieldId').value;
}

document.getElementById('buttonId').onclick = setTextFieldToValue;
```